# Pasar detalle de fragment a otro con click, erro de searchview

Tags: android, recyclerview, fragment, onclick

Hola amigos tengo un problemilla en el que entre despues de implementar un searchview en mi fragment.
Como veran ahi esta la lista de items y si hago click a cada uno me muestra el detalle correctamente.
[image: Listado de items]
[image: Lista filtrada]
Al hacer una busqueda, me muestra los item filtrados correspondientes, pero cuando hago click en el item me carga los datos o detalle de la lista sin filtrar, ahi esta mi problema. Quisiera una ayuda para solucionar este inconveniente.

Muestro ejemplo de mi codigo del adapter personalizado

```
public class TiendaRVAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<TiendaRVAdapter.ViewHolder> implements View.OnClickListener, Filterable{

private List<Tienda> mDataset;
private List<Tienda> mFilteredDataset;
private View.OnClickListener listener;

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if(listener != null){
        listener.onClick(v);
    }
}

@Override
public Filter getFilter() {
    return new Filter() {
        @Override
        protected FilterResults performFiltering(CharSequence constraint) {
            String charString = constraint.toString();
            if(charString.isEmpty()){
                mFilteredDataset = mDataset;
            } else {
                List<Tienda> newFilteredList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (Tienda tienda: mDataset){
                    if(tienda.getNombre().toLowerCase().contains(charString)){
                        newFilteredList.add(tienda);
                    }
                }
                mFilteredDataset = newFilteredList;
            }
            FilterResults filterResults = new FilterResults();
            filterResults.values = mFilteredDataset;
            return filterResults;
        }

        @Override
        protected void publishResults(CharSequence constraint, FilterResults results) {
            mFilteredDataset = (List<Tienda>) results.values;
            notifyDataSetChanged();
        }
    };
}

public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
    Context context;

    private TextView txtNombreTienda;
    private TextView txtCategoriaTienda;
    private TextView txtUbicacionTienda;
    private ImageView imageTienda;
    private CardView cardTienda;

    public ViewHolder(View v) {
        super(v);
        context = v.getContext();
        txtNombreTienda = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtNombreTienda);
        txtCategoriaTienda = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoriaTienda);
        txtUbicacionTienda = (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.txtUbicacionTienda);
        imageTienda = (ImageView) v.findViewById(R.id.imageTienda);
        cardTienda = (CardView) v.findViewById(R.id.cardTienda);
    }
}

public void add(int position, Tienda item) {
    mFilteredDataset.add(position, item);
    notifyItemInserted(position);
}

public void remove(Tienda item) {
    int position = mDataset.indexOf(item);
    mDataset.remove(position);
    notifyItemRemoved(position);
}

public TiendaRVAdapter(List<Tienda> myDataset) {
    this.mDataset = myDataset;
    this.mFilteredDataset = myDataset;
}

@Override
public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {

    View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_shop, parent, false);
    ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
    v.setOnClickListener(this);
    return vh;
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    YoYo.with(Techniques.FlipInX).duration(1500).playOn(holder.cardTienda);
    //YoYo.with(Techniques.ZoomInLeft).duration(1500).playOn(holder.imageTienda);
    holder.txtNombreTienda.setText(mFilteredDataset.get(position).getNombre());
    holder.txtCategoriaTienda.setText(mFilteredDataset.get(position).getCategoria());
    holder.txtUbicacionTienda.setText(mFilteredDataset.get(position).getNivel_ubicacion());
    Glide.with(holder.imageTienda.getContext()).load(mFilteredDataset.get(position).getLogo()).diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.ALL).into(holder.imageTienda);
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    if (mFilteredDataset != null)
        return mFilteredDataset.size();
    return 0;
}

public void setOnClickListener(View.OnClickListener listener){
    this.listener = listener;
}
```

}

Mi fragment:

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_shops, container, false);

    spnCategorias = (Spinner) vista.findViewById(R.id.spnCategorias);
    imgSinConexion = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imgSinConexion);
    imgSinConexion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    txtSinConexion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtSinConexion);
    txtSinConexion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
    textView = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.textView);

    ConnectivityManager con = (ConnectivityManager) getContext().getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    NetworkInfo nInfo = con.getActiveNetworkInfo();
    if(nInfo!= null && nInfo.isConnected()){
        imgSinConexion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        txtSinConexion.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        getCategories();
        sendRequest();
    } else {
        imgSinConexion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        txtSinConexion.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        spnCategorias.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        textView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "No se pudo conectar, verifique el acceso a internet e intente nuevamente", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }

    mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerTienda);
    mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
    mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
    mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

    return vista;
}


@Override
public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

public void onButtonPressed(Uri uri) {
    if (mListener != null) {
        mListener.onFragmentInteraction(uri);
    }
}

@Override
public void onDetach() {
    super.onDetach();
    mListener = null;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextSubmit(String query) {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onQueryTextChange(String newText) {
    mAdapter.getFilter().filter(newText);

    return false;
}

@Override
public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
    super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
    getActivity().getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    MenuItem menuItem = menu.findItem(R.id.action_search);
    SearchView searchView = (SearchView) MenuItemCompat.getActionView(menuItem);
    searchView.setOnQueryTextListener(this);
    return;
}

public interface OnFragmentInteractionListener {
    void onFragmentInteraction(Uri uri);
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    if(context instanceof Activity){
        this.activity = (Activity) context;
        interfaceShop = (IComunicaFragments) this.activity;
    }
}

private void sendRequest(){

    JsonObjectRequest solicitud = new JsonObjectRequest(JSON_URL, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            try {
                String datos = response.getString("response");
                JSONArray array = new JSONArray(datos);
                TiendaParse pj = new TiendaParse(""+ array);
                pj.parseTienda();
                mDataset = pj.getShops();
                mAdapter = new TiendaRVAdapter(mDataset);
                mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
                mAdapter.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(View v) {
                        //Toast.makeText(getActivity(),"Selecionó "+mDataset.get(mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        interfaceShop.sendShop(mDataset.get(mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v)));
                    }
                });
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),"Error "+ error,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    });
    VolleySingleton.getInstanciaVolley(getContext()).addToRequestQueue(solicitud);
}
```

En mi mainactivity implemento la interfaz para llamar al fragment del detalle y sus elementos:

```
DetailShopFragment detalleTienda;

@Override
public void sendShop(Tienda shop) {
    detalleTienda = new DetailShopFragment();
    Bundle bundleEnvio = new Bundle();
    bundleEnvio.putSerializable("tienda", shop);
    detalleTienda.setArguments(bundleEnvio);
    getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().replace(R.id.layout_main,detalleTienda).addToBackStack(null).commit();
    setTitle(R.string.title_detail_shop);
}
```

Fragment detalle:

```
 @Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View vista = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_detail_shop, container, false);

    txtTienda = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtTienda);
    txtCategoria = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtCategoria);
    txtUbicacion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtUbicacion);
    txtVerMapa = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtVerMapa);
    txtHorario = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtHorario);
    txtTelefono = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtTelefono);
    txtDescripcion = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtDescripcion);
    imgTienda = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imgTienda);

    txtSinPromos = (TextView) vista.findViewById(R.id.txtSinPromos);
    imgSinPromos = (ImageView) vista.findViewById(R.id.imgSinPromos);

    imgSinPromos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    txtSinPromos.setVisibility(View.GONE);

    Bundle tienda = getArguments();
    Tienda shop= null;
    if (tienda != null){
        shop= (Tienda) tienda.getSerializable("tienda");
        Glide.with(getActivity()).load(shop.getFoto()).centerCrop().into(imgTienda);
        txtTienda.setText(shop.getNombre());
        txtCategoria.setText(shop.getCategoria());
        txtUbicacion.setText(shop.getNivel_ubicacion());
        txtHorario.setText(shop.getHorario());
        txtTelefono.setText(shop.getTelefono());
        txtDescripcion.setText(shop.getDescripcion());

        final Tienda finalShop = shop;

        MapeoDialog = new Dialog(getActivity());
        txtVerMapa.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                showPopUp(v,finalShop.getFoto_ubicacion());
                Toast.makeText(v.getContext(),"Ubicación: "+ finalShop.getNivel_ubicacion(),Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        mRecyclerView = (RecyclerView) vista.findViewById(R.id.RecyclerPromo);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(),LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        getPromociones(finalShop.getId());
    }
    return vista;
}
```

Comment: Estas obteniendo el item de la lista no filtrada. Debes crear una interfaz que te devuelva la posición del item clickado, en la lista no filtrada antes de invocar el onClick del listener del adaptador y luego, obtener dicho valor de manera global en el Fragment. Por ejemplo: "Juan", "Pedro". "Juan" representa la posición 0 de la lista en la lista no filtrada. Pero si filtro la lista por "Pedro", ahora sería "Pedro" la posición 0 de la lista filtrada, pero el 1 en la original, y como estas obteniendo el valor 0 al hacer click, te dará el detalle de "Juan".

Comment: interfaceShop.sendShop(mDataset.get(mRecyclerView.getChildAdapterPosition(v))); Si te fijas estas obteniendo la posición de un View que no es su posición original, después de filtrar. Debes pasarle la posición que representa el item en la lista original (mDataset) ya que luego de filtrar si en total hay 3 items en el RecyclerView y 10 en la lista original, los Views representarán 0, 1 y 2 posiciones. Pero sus items pueden representar posiciones diferentes en la lista original (mDataset).